# Keyboard and mouse becomes unresponsive inside a Remote Desktop via VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm having a problem where during a Remote Desktop session over a VPN that I lose keyboard and mouse within the Remote Desktop.  I can see the screen refreshing, so it's not entirely hanging.  Sometimes it just comes back, sometimes it works if I reconnect the RD, sometimes it works if I reconnect the VPN, sometimes nothing works.

Here's my setup:
Client machine - Windows 7 Ultimate
Server machine - Windows XP SP 3

I'm unsure what other information would be appropriate, so please feel free to ask for specific information about the RDP or the VPN.

Comment: Given the symptoms bandwidth issues seem very likely.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to verify that? I know bandwidth is not an issue on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms that you are describing are symptomatic to not enough bandwidth or very high latency (which may be a hint towards high link utilization).

If ICMP is enabled across the VPN link, what are the "ping" response times over time between the RDP client and the RDP server? Does the response times remain consistent or does it fluctuate, if so what is the jitter variance?

Does the symptom changes occur across different times of the day or with different traffic loads across the VPN link? Are there any other applications sharing the VPN link?

Comment: +1. We have this during file transfers over our VPN link - ping times go from 80ms to 350+ms and people get "hanging sluggy connections".